# Rescaling colormap in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm switching from Matlab to Python and looking for a way to rescale the gray colormap of plt `image`. As I understand, `plt.imshow()` normalizes data to [0,1] and then to [0,255] when saved as an image file. However, I would like to normalize `image` to [0,160], for example. In Matlab it would be simply `imshow(rescale(image,0,160/255))`; however I don't see a similar straightforward method in Python.

I tried

> plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=160)

Which gave me a completely black image as well as

> plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=160./255)

resulting in an overexposure image.

Do I have to renormalize the data "manually" before plotting it, or does exist a more straightforward way to do it?

Comment: Are you sure that the values in your current `image` array are between 0 and 160? If the first command gave you a black image, they probably already are in the range 0-1.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen, I am sure that they aren't normalized to [0,160] nor [0,1], that is why I am asking if there is a straightforward way to renormalize data in Python similar to the `rescale()` function in Matlab.